# Python CTYPE structure :: How to set value ( A.B.dataType ) -- Confused which point is the error

Tags: python, python-2.7, ctypes

Below is mentioned is my structure

```
class CameraDevTMsgType(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("Cmd", ctypes.c_char), ("width", ctypes.c_int), ("height", ctypes.c_int), ("brightness", ctypes.c_int),
                ("contrast", ctypes.c_int), ("saturation", ctypes.c_int), ("gain", ctypes.c_int),
                ("quality", ctypes.c_int), ("file", ctypes.c_char * 20), ("device", ctypes.c_char * 20),
                ("nextcmd", ctypes.c_char * 20), ("delay", ctypes.c_int)]


class CameraMsgType(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("Status", ctypes.c_int), 
                ("Cmd", ctypes.c_int),
                ("settings", CameraDevTMsgType), 
                ("dateFormat", ctypes.c_int),
                ("DBdate", ctypes.c_char * 11),
                ("DBtime", ctypes.c_char * 9),
                ("isDeposit", ctypes.c_char * 2)]
```

Confies how to set value for field **file** in **CameraDevTMsgType** using **CameraMsgType** instance
like:

```
s=CameraMsgType()
s.settings.file = "XXXX"
```

How achieve this when i try this it shows exception

Comment: What error do you get? That code works fine when I try `s.settings.file = "xxxx"`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe :: Ooops it works absolutely fine..

Comment: unrelated: are you sure `settings` is `CameraDevTMsgType` and not `POINTER(CameraDevTMsgType)`?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian :sure not